# Cannot install watir on ruby 2.0 because of rubyzip

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, rubyzip

I'm trying to install watir. Had to upgrade my ruby installation so I installed rvenv and then used it to install ruby v2.0.

```
Sagis-MacBook-Air:~ sagism$ rbenv shell 2.0.0-rc2
Sagis-MacBook-Air:~ sagism$ ruby -v
    ruby 2.0.0dev (2013-02-08 trunk 39161) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
Sagis-MacBook-Air:~ sagism$ sudo gem install watir
    ERROR:  Error installing watir:
        rubyzip requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
```

I tried to install ruby 1.9.4 but then I get another error which I cannot resolve (different issue).

Comment: show us please an outpus of `sudo ruby -v`, and also `sudo cat $(which gem) | grep "#\!"`

Comment: You nailed the problem on the head. I didn't realized that sudo undid the env changes rvenv applies. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you ruby environment isn't dropped by `sudo` command:

```
$ sudo ruby -v

ruby 2.0.0dev (2013-02-08 trunk 39161) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
```

If your environment has reset:

```
$ sudo ruby -v

ruby 1.8.7 [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
```

Add into `/etc/sudoers` string like follows, and be sure that you are in `wheel` group:

```
User_Alias WHEEL_USERS = %wheel
Defaults:WHEEL_USERS !env_reset
```

Of course you can do it for any group you wish, this should prevent to drop the current environment, when you have to `sudo`, then try again:

```
$ sudo ruby -v

ruby 2.0.0dev (2013-02-08 trunk 39161) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
```

Answer (score -1):

> sudo update-alternatives --config gem

and select the correct version